# React this.props.children.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unstated

I'm making a react app with unstated to manage the state of my app, the application is a simple CRUD of notes.

I have a NoteList component to render the list of Notes.
This is my render() function in NoteList Component:

```
render() {
        return (
            <Subscribe to={[NoteContainer]}>
                {noteContainer => (
                    noteContainer.state.isLoaded ?
                        (
                            noteContainer.state.notas.map((note, i) => {
                                return (<Note note={note} index={i} onRemoveNote={this.removeNote} onEditNote={this.saveEditNote} key={i}></Note>)
                            })
                        )
                        :
                        (
                            <div>Loading Notes...</div>
                        )
                    )}
                )}
            </Subscribe>
        )
}
```

However, when i load the page, i get the following error:

> this6.props.children.apply is not a function

And in the chrome console the next description:

> The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in Consumer (created by Subscribe)
>       in Subscribe (at NoteList.js:19)
>       in NoteList (at App.js:160)
>       in Provider (created by Consumer)
>       in Consumer (created by Provider)
>       in Provider (at App.js:159)
>       in App (at src/index.js:7)

I have no clue on what could be the source of this error, if anyone can give me any help i would appreciate it!

Thanks in advance, have a nice day!

Comment: The children of `<Subscribe />` is a function that returns childrens, i think thats why the error

Comment: Is Subscribe your custom Component ? If so can you please share that

Comment: @Vencovsky, perhaps, i'm trying to make a workaround.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, no, Subscribe is a custom Unstated component

Comment: What is inside your `Subscribe` component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The children of `<Subscribe />` is a function that returns array of childrens, thats why the error. 
To check it, inside `<Subscribe />`, you could do `console.log(this.props.children)`and you will see that it's an array, you can't use apply in an array, you need to loop through and apply it to each children

```
this.props.children.map(children => children.apply())
```

Comment: Your answer gave me a clue to resolve the issue, i decided to move the logic of rendering the notes to another function. 
return (
            <Subscribe to={[NoteContainer]}>
                {noteContainer => (
                    noteContainer.showNotas()
                )}
            </Subscribe>
        )